# I'm running a MySQL DB Script and it says I have a syntax error. I do not see where the syntax error is. This is the error and this is the script

Tags: mysql, syntax

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `stre' at line 1

THIS IS THE SCRIPT:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema full-stack-ecommerce
-- -----------------------------------------------------

USE `full-stack-ecommerce`;

--
-- Prep work
--
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `order_item`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

--
-- Table structure for table `address`
--
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Table structure for table `customer`
--
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Table structure for table `orders`
--
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_tracking_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_billing_address_id` (`billing_address_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_shipping_address_id` (`shipping_address_id`),
  KEY `K_customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_billing_address_id` FOREIGN KEY (`billing_address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_shipping_address_id` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Table structure for table `order_items`
--
CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `K_order_id` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: `FK_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) - PRODUCT table is not in the published code - does it exist?

Comment: yes it exists thank you for your answer. For some reason I just removed the comments like:
 --
-- Table structure for table `address`
--
And executed each Table creation seperately and it worked.

Comment: I'm running MYSQL version 8.0.13 maybe for this version there is a problem with the script structure

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e22fa4f755aac45df3ef8ff68634fc3 or locally to me- albeit I don't know the product definition. Perhaps some none printing characters have crept in..

Comment: The problematic statement is ```CREATE TABLE `address` (...```. There is no any visible problem in it. Error message citates the statement starting from the backtick which wraps `id` column name - 99% that there is some non-printable illegal char between this backtick and previous opening parenthesis. Try to remove all chars (spaces, linebreaks) between these two symbols. Do NOT use text processors - simple text editor (like notepad) only. PS. How do you execute this script? precisely and in details..

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `full-stack-ecommerce`.`product` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` DECIMAL(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` BIT DEFAULT 1,
  `units_in_stock` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_created` DATETIME(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` DATETIME(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Comment: This is the product table ^

Comment: Indeed I think some whitespace that I cannot see. But it has been resolved thank you for your effort everyone. I made sure to run each "Create Table" seperately from the script and it worked =)